# How to fix the position of (0, 0) to (current page.south west) for every tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I need to draw severals tikz picture of varying size.
Each picture is on a separate page.
The coordinate system should be fixed, though.
Whenever I do

```
\node at (0, 0) {hello};
```

'hello' should be on the page bottom left corner (current page.south west).

So the coordinate system in tikz should look like this

```
-------------------------------------  
|          (page width, page height)|  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|                                   |  
|(0, 0)                             |  
-------------------------------------
```

**MWE**

```
% the node with 'two' is way below the node with 'one'

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0, 0) {one};

\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage

\vspace*{5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0, 0) {two};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

(in the screenshot color are inverted, normally the background is white)

[image]

Comment: Name your coordinate something and use `baseline=(<node name>)` if all your pictures appear in left aligned pages

Comment: @percusse I tried `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current page.south west)]` unsuccesfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shift the origin point of a `tikzpicture` by adding the option `shift`, like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(5,0)}]
```

In this case for example, I shift the origin to `5,0`. In your case, you'd have to write `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.south west)}]`, but keep in mind that your node will actually be *there* at the corner of the page.

You can of course use anchors, so adding `\node[anchor=south west] ...` will pin the node at the bottom left corner.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.south west)}]
    \node at (0,0) {one};
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage
\vspace*{5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.south west)}]
    \node at (0,0) {two};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe something is missing. When I try your code, I get the same output as the picture in my question. Do you get a different output?

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton If you paste my code in a new (empty) document, does it work?

Comment: No, same output as in my picture. I do '% arara: pdflatex', and its 'tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)'

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton Mmh not sure what is going on.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton Did you compile **twice**?

Comment: @cfr I was compiling once, compiling twice fix it. Thanks.